Framer-motion animations don't relaunch when I change product page
When I change page on the site all my animations are launched, when I go once to the product page they are launched too but when I switch from one product to another the animations are not relaunched. There are no reloads on the site, which is normal, but which would have directly solved my problem.
app.js
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import NotFound from "./pages/NotFound/NotFound";
import Layout from "./pages/Layout";
import Error from "./pages/Error/Error";
import Contact from "./pages/Contact";
import About from "./pages/About";
import Team from "./pages/Team";
import Jobs from "./pages/Jobs";
import TermsConditions from "./pages/TermsConditions";
import PrivacyCookiePolicy from "./pages/PrivacyCookiePolicy";
import BookADemo from "./pages/BookADemo";
import Blog from "./pages/Blog";
import BlogArticle from "./pages/BlogArticle";
import Product from "./pages/Product";
import { strapiLoader, strapiLoaderBlog } from "./data/loaders/loaders";
import Testimonial from "./pages/Testimonial";

export const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        element: <Layout />,
        errorElement: <Error />,
        children: [
            {
                path: "/",
                element: <Home />,
            },
            {
                path: "*",
                element: <NotFound />,
            },
            {
                path: "/contact",
                element: <Contact />,
            },
            {
                path: "/about",
                element: <About />,
            },
            {
                path: "/team",
                element: <Team />,
            },
            {
                path: "/jobs",
                element: <Jobs />,
            },
            {
                path: "/terms-conditions",
                element: <TermsConditions />,
            },
            {
                path: "/privacy-cookie-policy",
                element: <PrivacyCookiePolicy />,
            },
            {
                path: "/product/:slug",
                element: <Product />,
            },
            {
                path: "/book-a-demo",
                element: <BookADemo />,
            },
            {
                path: "/blog",
                element: <Blog />,
                loader: strapiLoader(``),
            },
            {
                path: "/blog/:documentId",
                element: <BlogArticle />,
                loader: ({ params }) => strapiLoaderBlog(params.documentId),
            },
            {
                path: "/testimonial",
                element: <Testimonial />,
            },
        ],
    },
]);

index.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import { router } from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-bootstrap";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
        <ToastContainer />
    </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();

product.jsx
import { useRef } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import { cleanSlugUrl } from "../helpers/cleanSlugUrl";
import { dataProducts } from "../data/DataProducts";
import Accordion from "react-bootstrap/Accordion";
import Card from "../components/Card";
import CallToActionAndNewsletter from "../components/CallToActionAndNewsletter";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { useInView } from "framer-motion";
import { fadeInUp, variantsGroupI } from "../helpers/animations";

export default function Product() {
    const refFaq = useRef(null);
    const isFaqInView = useInView(refFaq, { once: true });

    const { slug } = useParams();
    const product = dataProducts.find(item => cleanSlugUrl(item.title) === slug);

    if (!product) {
        return <div>Product not found</div>;
    }

    const { title, secondSlider, slogan, logo, alt, faqData } = product;

    return (
        <Container>
            <article className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center py-5">
                <h1 className="fs-8 fs-9 fw-bold text-center text-uppercase">{title}</h1>
                <p className="fs-1 mb-5 text-center text-uppercase">{slogan}</p>
                <div className="w-50 h-50 mt-3 mx-auto d-md-none">
                    <img className="w-100" src={logo} alt={alt} />
                </div>

                <Row>
                    {product.productDescription.map((item, i) => {
                        return item.isImage && item.image ? (
                            <Col md={4} key={item.id} className="mt-4 text-center d-none d-md-flex ">
                                <div className="w-50 h-50 mt-3 mx-auto position-relative">
                                    <img className="w-100" src={item.image} alt={item.title} />
                                    {item.badgeArray.map((badge, j) => {
                                        return (
                                            <div key={j} className={badge.classNameBadge}>
                                                <img src={badge.badge} alt="" width={100} height={100} className="object-fit-contain d-none d-xl-flex" />
                                            </div>
                                        );
                                    })}
                                </div>
                            </Col>
                        ) : (
                            <motion.div
                                custom={i}
                                initial="hidden"
                                animate="visible"
                                variants={variantsGroupI}
                                key={item.id}
                                className={`ps-5 ps-md-0 position-relative col-md-4 ${item.additionalStyleParentDiv}`}>
                                <h4 className="fw-bold">{item.title}</h4>
                                <span>{item.description}</span>
                                <div className={item.classNameBadge}>
                                    <img src={item.badge} alt="" width={25} height={25} />
                                </div>
                            </motion.div>
                        );
                    })}
                </Row>

                <Row className="bg-gradient-gray-light my-5 pb-4 px-4 rounded-2">
                    <h2 className="fs-9 my-5 text-uppercase text-center">Features</h2>
                    {secondSlider.map((feature, i) => (
                        <Col md={4} lg={3} key={i} className="d-flex mb-4">
                            <Card
                                key={feature.id}
                                img={feature.img}
                                alt={feature.alt}
                                title={feature.title}
                                description={feature.description}
                                ImgHeight={50}
                                ImgWidth={50}
                                className="h-100"
                            />
                        </Col>
                    ))}
                </Row>

                <Row className="w-100">
                    <motion.div
                        initial={fadeInUp.initial}
                        animate={isFaqInView ? fadeInUp.animate : fadeInUp.initial}
                        transition={fadeInUp.transition}
                        ref={refFaq}>
                        <Col sm={12}>
                            <h2 className="fs-9 my-5 text-uppercase text-center">Frequently asked questions</h2>

                            <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
                                {faqData.map((faq, index) => (
                                    <Accordion.Item eventKey={index.toString()} key={faq.id}>
                                        <Accordion.Header>{faq.question}</Accordion.Header>
                                        <Accordion.Body>{faq.answer}</Accordion.Body>
                                    </Accordion.Item>
                                ))}
                            </Accordion>
                        </Col>
                    </motion.div>

                    <Col sm={12}>
                        <CallToActionAndNewsletter
                            title="want to see what we can do for you?"
                            description="Action speaks louder than words and your listeners will tell you where to go with their listening patterns. All you need to do is listen."
                            link="/book-a-demo"
                            nameLink="i want a free online demo"
                            smallText="See first hand, how would benefit your station. It’s completely obligation free!"
                        />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </article>
        </Container>
    );
}

I tried <AnimatePresence mode={'wait'}> and lots of other things found on the internet but nothing worked.
